# How to create bootstrap labels like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, label

[image]

I wanted to create input like this. When you click the label, a violet line appears. When you click on the success input, green line appears below the label. When you click on the error line input, red line appears below the input.

i want to create using html and css

Comment: where is your tried code?

Comment: Try this it will help http://mdbootstrap.com/components/forms/

Comment: It's called "Material Design" and there are different packages. Here is a kinda stunning one for free: [Material Design Bootstrap](http://mdbootstrap.com/material-design-for-bootstrap/)

Comment: This type of labels on Material Design Framework there. Read this: [The 15 Best Material Design Frameworks and Libraries](http://tutorialzine.com/2016/03/the-15-best-material-design-frameworks-and-libraries/)

Comment: i can't create this without Material Design framework?

Comment: This may help you http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way you can do this with pure HTML and CSS.

Maybe you can even optimize the code but I wanted to give you a quick idea.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
  <label for="name"></label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:focus ~ label:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo**

[Codepen Pen](http://codepen.io/svelts/pen/mALkdX?editors=1100#0)

> **Material Inputs with a floating Label**
>
> For those of you who want to add the functionality of floating labels.

I tried to keep the HTML structure as similar as possible compared to the first idea. Got it finally working with this structure. Simply removed the placeholder tag from the input and added a data attribute on the parent div called placeholder. This is needed for the swipe up effect later on the input focus.
Also you will need a little bit JavaScript because you have to add a class to the parent element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper" data-placeholder="Username">
    <input id="name" type="text" />
    <label for="name"></label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:focus ~ label:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.wrapper.clicked:before {
  color: #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

 .wrapper.clicked.filled:before {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input").focus(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("clicked");
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("filled");
  }
});

$("input").blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("filled");
  } else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("clicked filled");
  }
});
```

**Demo**

[Codepen Pen](http://codepen.io/svelts/pen/xEzKKZ)

Comment: Your code works! the code in codepen is not working for me ... Thanks a lot

Comment: If i want a floating label, what should i do?

Comment: @prathanadan Good question. Although this will make the code a bit more complex, I think I've found a solution in which you don't have to change too much on the HTML structure. If you want I could give you the link to the pen I've made but since the last one didn't work for you I could also post it here as an new answer or edit the old one but I'm not sure if this is allowed.

Comment: Give me the link , i would give a try! If you can post or edit also not a problem!

Comment: @prathanadan Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a bare minumum implementation.

```css
input[type="text"] {
 outline: none;
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 margin: 5px 15px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
}

.has-success input:focus, .has-success input:active {
 border-bottom: 1px solid green;
 color: green;
}

.has-error input:focus, .has-error input:active {
 border-bottom: 1px solid red;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-success">
  <input type="text" value="success">
</div>

<div class="has-error">
  <input type="text" value="error">
</div>
```